# How do I add a keymap into fish vi keybindings?

Tags: vi, keymap, fish

I've just started using fish and I'm loving using the vi keybindings it provides.

I wanted though to add a custom keymap that I use in vi. I usually map `space+c` in visual mode to yank to `"*` (system clipboard). How can I add such keymap in fish?

I'm using fish 3.3.1 on MacOS 12.

Edit:
I've tried this

```
bind -M visual \x20c '"*y'
```

And got the following error

```
fish: Unexpected end of string, quotes are not balanced
```

Also tried with a modifier instead of space and got the same result.

Comment: This is the right forum for the question, but you might get more traction on stackoverflow.

Comment: @glennjackman last time I asked something about fish there, they closed my question saying it should be here ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Did you read [Custom bindings](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/interactive.html#custom-bindings) in the fish docs?

Comment: I agree it's probably not on-topic on SO, but you might also consider the [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) Stack.  It's definitely on-topic here as well, so I'd just leave it for now.

Comment: @glennjackman I've edited the question with my findings, but I still can't do it

Comment: @Augusto What happens with `bind -M visual \20c fish_clipboard_copy`?  It's not working for me, but I'm on WSL, where the clipboard operates quite differently.  If it works, then I'll add it as an answer.  If not, we'll keep working on it :-)

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, that works for me: `bind \x20v fish_clipboard_paste` and then "space v" pastes (I use emacs mode). When I type `bind` to list bindings, it shows me `bind ' v' fish_clipboard_paste`

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for confirming.  I also notice that the OP is using `"*y`, which has a default Fish binding of `'commandline -s | xsel -p; commandline -f end-selection repaint-mode'`, so that's a likely candidate for binding to `\x20c` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of possibilities:

- First, if you are currently using <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to yank to the system clipboard, then you can see via `bind` in Fish that the default binding is:

  ```
  bind -M visual -m default '"*y' 'commandline -s | xsel -p; commandline -f end-selection repaint-mode'
  ```

  So you should be able to recreate that for <kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> by:

  ```
  bind -M visual -m default \x20c 'commandline -s | xsel -p; commandline -f end-selection repaint-mode'
  ```
- There's also the `fish_clipboard_copy` function listed in the [docs](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/bind.html#cmd-bind) for `bind`, so another possibility might be:

  ```
  bind -M visual -m default \20c fish_clipboard_copy
  ```

  ... but I assume you'll need to use the converse `fish_clipboard_paste` as well, rather than `xsel`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the binding is setting a command that is not valid. You cannot run `"*y` at the command line (and if you try with `fish -c '"*y'`, you'll get the same error).

The command to `bind` needs to be just that - a command. That's why using `fish_clipboard_copy` works fine. There's no way to execute another keybinding, at least in fish 3.3.1 and before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to put a binding on two "plain" characters.
When [the documentation for `bind`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/bind.html) refers to a "sequence of characters", I think it means zero or more modifiers (ctrl, alt, shift) followed by a "regular" character.

I have bindings for `!!` and `!$` to mimic what bash does with those, and it looks like this:

```
function bind_bang
    switch (commandline -t)[-1]
    case "!"
        commandline -t $history[1]; commandline -f repaint
    case "*"
        commandline -i !
    end
end

function bind_dollar
    switch (commandline -t)[-1]
    case "!"
        commandline -t ""
        commandline -f history-token-search-backward
    case "*"
        commandline -i '$'
    end
end

bind ! bind_bang
bind '$' bind_dollar
```

Each binding function has to look for the *previous character* in the command line.

I don't use vi-mode in fish (I started using fish before it had a vi-mode, so my fingers got trained) -- I'm not sure how you're going to have to implement paste.

Comment: I get the same error if I try with a modifier. The issue is with the command

Comment: I'd recommend you seek more expert help: try gitter or the mailing list => https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#further-help-and-development

Comment: You can definitely bind a sequence of characters.